# Magento2 get system configuration shipping method value in phtml file

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, phtml

Inside admin from

```
Storage->Configuration->Sales->Shipping Method -> Free Shipping -> "Minimum Amount Value"
```

I want to get this textbox value in phtml file.
so how i can get that?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
){
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

echo $this->scopeConfig->getValue('carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

you will get minimum order amount of free shipping method.

Comment: Hello Abhishek, i want to get that value in any phtml file inside a block file it's working fine.
Thanks for reply

Comment: You can call it inside helper and that helper function will work in any phtml file